# How to get full file path on Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, fileinfo, directoryinfo

I'm using Asp.net treeview to show my directory including files. I want to show the file path once the user click on the treeview node. I'm using FullName property to get the path. The problem that I have is, treeview shows the full path only for the directory not for the file!

**Here is my code**

```
private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    TreeNode directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);

    foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        if (!directory.Attributes.ToString().Contains("Hidden"))
        {
            directoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
            directoryNode.Value = directoryInfo.FullName; // Here I'm passing the directory path
        }
    }

    foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        if (File.GetAttributes(file.FullName).ToString().IndexOf("Hidden") == -1)
        {
            directoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
            directoryNode.Value = file.FullName; // Here I'm passing the file path
        }
    }

    return directoryNode;
}
```

**Update**
For some reason full path is not showing **treeNode value** for the file but directory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set value to the wrong node.

Change

```
  directoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));  
  directoryNode.Value = file.FullName; // Here I'm passing the file path
```

To

```
  TreeNode fileNode = new TreeNode(file.Name, file.FullName);
  directoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(fileNode);
```

This will set Value of the file node to it`s Full path

Answer (score 0):

The [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.value.aspx) property is not displayed

Change

```
directoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
```

To

```
directoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.FullName));
```

Comment: Yes, it does work but I don't want to show the full file path on the tree node. Instead I want to pass it as a value.

Comment: I'm confused, what is it you're asking then? It sounded like you wanted the full path to be displayed on the file node

Comment: No, If you check my code, I'm trying to pass the FullName to treeNode value. Sorry, I need to be bit more clear, I'm trying to get the treeNode value and I couldn't get the full path.